On Bieberbach conjecture for typically real functions
I was reading a handout on complex analysis, which included the following exercise: if $f : \Delta \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an injective holomorphic typically real function on the unit disk (that is, $f(z)$ is real iff $z$ is real) and $f(z)=z+\sum_{n \geq 2} a_nz^n$, then $|a_n| \leq n$ for all $n \geq 2$.
It included the following hint, but even after applying it I was unable to solve it: "Write $\operatorname{Im} f(z)$ in polar coordinates and use the orthogonality formulas for $\sin(n\theta)$ to get $a_nr^n$".
Rewriting the imaginary part of $f$ in terms of $z$ written in polar coordinates, I obtained the identity $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \operatorname{Im} f(re^{i\theta}) \sin(n\theta) d\theta = \pi a_nr^n$$
However, I see no clear way to bound the left-hand side.

See Theorem 4.8 here: https://diposit.ub.edu/dspace/bitstream/2445/151979/2/151979.pdf (found with a Google search for “bieberbach conjecture for real functions”)

show that $\Im f$ is odd hence the integrand above is even so is twice the one $[0, \pi]$ where $\Im f \ge 0$, take absolute values and use $\sin |n\theta| \le n \sin \theta$ there
